# Is there a word for "to be of" something?

Tags: american-english

Does english have a word for the concept "to be of" something? One word?
It is hard for me to explain what I mean.
But such as the trees are of earth or a child is of a parent.. Maybe bad examples but might help build a picture.

Not just relating to, but to be directly of that something. A product of that something, basically.

Comment: It’s antiquated, but there’s ***begat***  the parent begat the child.  But what’s wrong with “is of”?  The creature was of the forest.

Comment: I read the phrase in a book by [Jerri Nielsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerri_Nielsen), who was the Base MD at South Pole.  She said of herself that she was "of the ice" and one of her e-mail correspondents described himself as "of the Sierra".  Nielsen meant that she was changed by and belonged in "the ice" of Antarctica.  Is this the usage you mean?   Her correspondent was formed by and belonged in the Sierra.  As for one word....I have to think.

Comment: "To be of"  is poetic and magical simplicity, why be searching more complicated , whereas "born of", for instance,  is limiting and / or brings nothing more ?

Comment: I suspect the answer is no. I can't think of any single-word solution, which would have to be a verb, that does the (very complex) job of expressing the act of having sprung from something. There always has to be a preposition - originate from, descend from, be the spawn of... It almost seems that English grammar doesn't have anything like this, but then neither do the other Germanic languages. But an answer like "no" would be very categorical so I'd rather leave it to the experts.

Comment: Anon, do you need it to be just one word? The closest I can come is *inherit* and that is not very close.

Comment: There are lots of examples of this, most of them to do with children real or metaphorical: "A child of war," "A child of poverty," "A child of the Eighties." But there's no particular word for that construction in general; it's just a standard way of expressing possession.

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard to say you have the answer already: *of*.

Based on your question, I gather that English is not your first language. "Of" and other such commonly used small (2-4 letter) words often contain considerable nuance of meaning. Most dictionaries have six, eight, ten entries for such words, and I have seen these confuse English learners, let alone native speakers.

[Oxford Online gives eight root entries for "of"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of). Each describes relationship between subjects and/or predicates.

If "of" fails to satisfy your poetic inclination, break open a thesaurus and start with the words that have already been suggested: made, born.

Answer (score 0):

A (clever) standard English construction is the **compound adjective**, which requires **two** words: a substantive + a past-participle/adjective.

To convey your specific idea of "production", you could use past participles such as "made", "born", "built", "crafted":

Examples:

> A man-made tool
>
> An Irish-born person
>
> A hand-made cookie
>
> A steel-built ship
>
> A wood-crafted spoon

So the first word would be roughly the "what/where from" and the second would be the "how".

There is no hard and fast rule on whether the two words should be separated by a a hyphen, a space or joined together (see [this explanation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/hyphen) about hyphens).